# Convert Action<T> to Action<object>

Tags: c#

How do I convert `Action<T>` to `Action<Object>` in C#?

Comment: The question does not make sense, you cannot create an Action<T>, you have to specify a type.

Comment: Guessing this one of those covariance/contravariance questions, else the answer would just be `Action<object>`.

Comment: You can't cast an open generic type to an Object, unless T is restricted to class. In code, Action<T> assigned to Action<Object> is legal when T : class. Steven, just to clarify this isn't probably solvable by covariance.

Comment: @Dykam: Yes, I believe you are correct. Covariance does not work for value types.

Comment: Sorry about that. T is of course a Generic Type.

Comment: @MagnusGladh - What they are saying is that being a Generic Type is not *sufficient*. The type must *also* have a constraint that ensures it is not a value type. E.g. `T : class`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here's a sample of what you ask for (type check can be added in last line to properly handle invalid cast exception to be more user-friendly):

```
public Action<object> Convert<T>(Action<T> myActionT)
{
    if (myActionT == null) return null;
    else return new Action<object>(o => myActionT((T)o));
}
```

May be you can give more details about the task though, because right now it looks a bit odd.

Comment: your else statement is redundant

Comment: @jperez - Its a matter of personal preference. Some of us prefer to see the `if`..  `else` .. structure. Even when `return` statements are involved. Reason: this puts statements *visually* at the same level (here, down one level) that are *logically* at the same level. That is, the two paths forward are chosen by the "condition" of the `if`; they can be viewed as both being "one level down" from the main flow. IMHO, the two styles - what you suggest, and what is done here - are equally valid. Its a trade-off as to what the coder chooses to emphasize.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have something like this:

```
void Foo(Action<object> action) { }

Action<something> myaction;
```

And want to convert myaction so you can pass it to Foo.

That doesn't work.

Foo can pass any object to the action whose type derives from object. But myaction accepts only objects that derive from something.

Answer (score 1):

You can add generic parameter like this

```
    Action<object> Function<T>(Action<T> act) where T : class
    {
        return (Action<object>)act;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't actually work

Comment: Possibly, you forgot `where T : class`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by converting... Action is the generic declaration of an action delegate... if you want an action delegate that works on 'object' you would do something like:

```
var myAction = new Action<object>(obj=> ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to do this today and stumbled upon this post.  Really, the only simple way I found to do it was to wrap Action<string> within a new Action<object>.  In my case, I was pushing my Actions into a Concurrent Dictionary, and then retrieving them by type.  Effectively, I was processing a queue of messages where actions could be defined to handle messages with a particular typed input.

```
var _actions = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<object>>();
Action<string> actionStr = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
var actionObj = new Action<object>(obj => { var castObj = (V)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(V)); actionStr(castObj); } );
_actions.TryAdd(typeof(string), actionObj);
```

Comment: That is a brilliant solution!  I too am using it for a similar situation as you

Comment: I was just bashing my head against a very similar issue, and realized there is a much simpler solution.

Instead of converting Action<specific> to Action<object> just store Action<specific> as an object and cast back to Action<specific> when invoking it.

It works since the key is the type, so you know when putting it in that it's the correct type.