# Dynamically convert Func to corresponding Action

Tags: c#, delegates, action, func

I'm trying to use the Convert method on functions as well as actions, so I can avoid writing duplicate methods taking in delegates of Func type. Convert method comes from [Convert Action<T> to Action<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444246/convert-actiont-to-actionobject)

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        var mi = program.GetType().GetMethod("Function", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        // Can be any version of Func
        var funcType = typeof(Func<int, int>);
        // Create action delegate somehow instead
        var del = mi.CreateDelegate(funcType, null);
        // Or dynamically convert the Func to a corresponding Action type (in this case Action<int>)
    }

    // Or find a way to pass it in as a parameter here
    public Action<object> Convert<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        return o => action((T)o);
    }

    public int Function(int five)
    {
        return five;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Does it not work the way you expect?

Comment: action has no return type

Comment: There's nothing wrong with my code, it's written to improve understanding. I just want to convert a Func variable to the corresponding Action variable dynamically.

Comment: My problem in a nutshell is the inability to do this: new Action<int>(program.Function);

Comment: `program.Fuction` is a method which you can pass as an `Action<int>`

Comment: @Stuart Please elaborate.

Comment: @Martin sure. [Action<T>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,486d58da4553e12d) is a delegate as you can see by viewing the source code. You can [read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) that "Any method from any accessible class or struct that matches the delegate type can be assigned to the delegate". Here `program.Function` is a `Func<int,int>` is that what you are saying you want to convert to `Action<T>`?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public static Action<T1> IgnoreResult<T1,T2>(Func<T1,T2> func)
{
    return x => func(x);
}
```

But for all variants of `Func<T1,T2....>`

I think this would work:

```
public static Action<TR> IgnoreResult<TR>(Delegate f)
{
    return x => f.DynamicInvoke(x);
}
```

With usage:

```
var action = IgnoreResult<int>(new Func<int,int>(program.Function));
action(5);
```

You'll not be able to get it to infer the parameters and return type without copy and pasting the first example for all variants of `Action<T1...>` and `Func<T1,T2...>`.

Comment: 1. Solution: As I mentioned in my question my goal is to have only one method that can be called for both Action and Func which leads us to
2. Solution: You create a delegate that is calling DynamicInvoke which is 30 times slower than invoking directly.

Comment: Right, so you want the best of both worlds =) That can be done but is fiddlier, I'll get back to you

Comment: I should tell you, you can't use dynamic keyword or expression trees. Unity doesn't support dynamic and expression trees are only supported in version 5.5.0 and above also LambdaExpression.Compile has so bad performance you'd have to call the delegate millions of times to earn back the initialization cost.

Comment: Ah, well that's my WIP out then, I cannot help you. With these strict constraints you really would be best copying the 10 or so methods needed